# How does DNS host like NameCheap secure and prevent anyone from creating an A record with your IP / domain name?

Tags: dns-hosting, namecheap

The only way I can think of is it surely checks the WHOIS record from the registrar to confirm the IP matches the domain name, but I can't find anything written about it.

Comment: It does not matter. Any nameserver can have any record on any name... until it receives delegation from the authoritative parent noone will query it so whatever it publishes has no force/no visibility on the Internet. Once it gets that delegation it means whoever owns that domain is able to prove its ownership by inserting a specific record (typically TXT or CNAME) generated "randomly" and as instructed by a given provider that can then check the owner is really who it pretends depending on if it is able to mutate the content of the zone or not.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a statement, not a question actually.

Comment: So I think the answer to that is that only trusted registrars that can verify site identity are allowed to make TLD operator API calls to create the delegation in the parent zone (.com)

Answer (score 2):

Regarding DNS hosting services in general, the service provider requires you to authenticate as relevant administrative user (typically the user that created the zone, or possibly some other user designated by that zone creator) before you can manage your DNS zones, and you can only modify records in your own zones. That makes it pretty simple and clear who can do what.

As for IP addresses, there is no limit in DNS in general which domains can have address records (`A`/`AAAA` records) that point to which IP addresses, that is just not something that has any limit, but the consequences of this are generally not that big.

Now, regarding who gets to create a zone with a DNS hosting service in the first place, that can sometimes be a bit of a problematic thing.
Sometimes there is some form of validation of domain ownership, sometimes there isn't. Regardless, domains can change owners over time and unless the ownership check is somehow done on a regular basis it can be made invalid at any point.
That means there can be a situation where someone else may have created the zone first and  effectively blocks the current domain owner from using that particular DNS service (without manual intervention).